# How to get the WAN IP from a router using UPnP/SSDP

Tags: router, ip, upnp, netcat

I'm trying to find a way to get my router to report back my WAN IP using UPnP/SSDP, but so far I have been unable to even get a list of UPnP supporting internet access devices on my network. Here's the request I'm sending:

```
$ cat request.txt
M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
MAN: "ssdp:discover"
MX: 3
ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1
```

With the command:

```
$ nc -uvv 239.255.255.250 1900 < request.txt
Connection to 239.255.255.250 1900 port [udp/ssdp] succeeded!
```

I just get the connnection succeded message and then nothing...

Could anyone give me any pointers (no [memory addresses](http://xkcd.com/138/) please!) as to what I'm doing wrong?

**Update:** Ok so I tried using `tcpdump` to get responses here's what I got:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -vv -A -s 0 -i en1 udp port 1900 and host 239.255.255.250 
…
NOTIFY * HTTP/1.1
Host: 239.255.255.250:1900
Cache-Control: max-age=60
Location: http://192.168.1.1:1780/InternetGatewayDevice.xml
NTS: ssdp:alive
Server: POSIX, UPnP/1.0 linux/5.100.104.2 
NT: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1
…
```

I guess the next step is to parse the output of tcpdump and filter out all responses that don't contain the `NT: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1` header then make the actual SOAP request to the router.

Comment: Why does your 'nc' command use two 'v' parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use `tcpdump` or something similar to see the reply or replies.

`nc` is looking for a reply from the endpoint you sent the request to. But the endpoint you sent the request to is a generic broadcast target. The reply will come not from a generic broadcast target but from the specific device that replies.

As `nc`'s output says, it has connected to the broadcast target. So it's not going to see the replies that come from the replying devices.

Answer (score 1):

Although, this task is rather old, I post the answer, I was looking for, myself.

Your UPnP-reply posted the location "http://192.168.1.1:1780/InternetGatewayDevice.xml"

There you can get more info about data format. For my router: I got there more paths to xmls.
Calling them, there is more UPnP info.
resulting in this:
I called:

```
POST /upnp/control?WANIPConnection HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.1
SOAPAction: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1#GetExternalIPAddress"
Accept-Language: de-de;q=1, de;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
User-Agent: gupnp-universal-cp GUPnP/0.20.10 DLNADOC/1.50
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 281

<?xml version="1.0"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:GetExternalIPAddress xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1"></u:GetExternalIPAddress></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

and get as answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
EXT:
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Date: Tue, 04 Aug 2015 23:55:01 GMT
Server: servername/2.0 UPnP/1.0 UPnP-Device-Host/1.0
Content-Length: 380

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <s:Body>
        <u:GetExternalIPAddressResponse xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1">
            <NewExternalIPAddress>123.123.123.123</NewExternalIPAddress>
        </u:GetExternalIPAddressResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I've got a lot of help from "UPnP Inspector"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `socat`

```
$ socat -T1 STDIO UDP4-DATAGRAM:239.255.255.250:1900 < request.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully working BASH script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function wan_ip_connection() {
    local host=$1
    result=$( curl -s "http://$host/upnp/control?WANIPConnection" \
       -H 'SOAPAction: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1#GetExternalIPAddress"' \
       --data-binary '<?xml version="1.0"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:GetExternalIPAddress xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1"></u:GetExternalIPAddress></s:Body></s:Envelope>'
    )

    REGEX='ExternalIPAddress>([0-9.]+)<'
    if [[ $result =~ $REGEX ]]
    then
       echo "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"
    fi
}

function initial_query() {
   echo -e 'M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: 239.255.255.250:1900\r\nMAN: "ssdp:discover"\r\nMX: 3\r\nST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1\r\n\r\n' |
       socat STDIO UDP4-DATAGRAM:239.255.255.250:1900
}

function main() {
   location=$( initial_query | grep LOCATION )
   location=${location%/*}
   location=${location##*/}
   ip=$( wan_ip_connection "$location" )
   echo $ip
}

main
```